# Is the static the only directory that can be accessed directly with an URL

Tags: python, security, flask

This is a question about security of resources. If I understand the design of Flask correct, we can access a resource, say, an image in the *static* directory with the URL:

```
https://{domain_name}/static/{image_name}.png
```

But what I want to be sure is whether or not any other directories, under default settings, will NOT be accessible in the same way. That is to say, suppose a client want to access an image in another directory, for example, *images*, the general process is like the following:

1. The client sends a post/get request to the Flask server to let the program know it wants some resources;
2. Flask program will locate the image by the post/get request sent by the client;
3. Flask program will check if the client is logged in and authorized to access the requested image. It could reject the request if a client is not logged in/unauthorized;
4. If the Flask program thinks everything is okay, it return the requested image to the client with something like `return send_file(filename, mimetype='image/png')`
5. By default setting, the client canNOT simply type: `https://{domain_name}/images/{image_name}.png` to access the image or somehow circumvent Flask to access the image.

Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is broadly correct, but you shouldn't be sending requests directly to Flask in the first place - a reverse proxy or load balancer should be between your app and the outside world. That can serve the contents of `/static/` directly far more efficiently than Flask ever will

Comment: Thanks @daveruinseverything, could you please take a look if this setting meets what you said: I use Apache as a gateway. Internally, my flask program listens on port 127.0.0.1:8888 and Apache redirects the external 443/80 traffic to 127.0.0.1:8888. Does this achieve what you mentioned?